Сan’t turn off the selection when I hold down the button for a long time in the NavigationRail widget. Flutter
We use the NavigationRail widget, when we click on a navigation element, we change the icon. When we long press, a gray oval appears, which needs to be removed. How to do this?
enter image description here
Code example:
SizedBox _menuContainer() {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 310,
    child: Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Material(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.transparent, // Отключаем эффект всплеска
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent, // Отключаем эффект выделения
          child: NavigationRail(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xff070710),
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            destinations: <NavigationRailDestination>[
              for (int index = 0; index < imagePaths.length; index++)
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Material(
                    color: Colors
                        .transparent, // Устанавливаем цвет фона на прозрачный
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor:
                          Colors.transparent, // Отключаем эффект всплеска
                      highlightColor:
                          Colors.transparent, // Отключаем эффект выделения
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedIndex = index;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 46,
                        height: 46,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: _selectedIndex == index
                              ? const Color(0xFF6F6AFF) // Цвет выделения
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            _selectedIndex == index
                                ? whiteImagePaths[index]
                                : imagePaths[index],
                            width: 28,
                            height: 28,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  label: const SizedBox.shrink(), // Пустая метка
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Tried to disable via "useIndicator: false", and also via disabling indicatorShape. A gray oval still appears
